# Functions in $A(\mathbb{C})$ that vanish at zero

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $A\subset L^{\infty}(-\pi,\pi)$ be the closed subspace spanned by $\{e^{inx}\}_{n\geq0}$, i.e., all continuous functions on the unit circle that are uniform limits of trigonometric polynomials of the form $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}e^{ikx}$. Is it true that if $f\in A$ and $f(0)=0$, then $\int f\;dm=0$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure? This fact is used several times in “Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions” but I have no idea why it is true.

[image]

Comment: Why it should be true? Just take $1-\cos x$ one condition is that the sum of the Fourier coefficients is zero, the other is that the zeroth ("constant term") Fourier coefficient is zero

Comment: @Conrad I added a picture of the book I’m reading. It seems like this is what they’re claiming.

Comment: You are reading the book wrongly . It says for  'For every $f$ in $A$....'. Doesn't say anything about a particular function with $f(0)=0$ and $f \in A$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I’m not following. Does the corollary not imply that Lebesgue measure is such a measure (if a multiple of Lebesgue has the property then so will Lebesgue)?

Comment: You are probably thinking of  the converse of the corollary. Converse are not always true.

Comment: If such a $\mu$ exists then the converse would follow. The way he’s writing makes it seem that the converse is the obvious direction.

Comment: I guess the corollary to the corollary would be that all such measures are trivial.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what $f(0)$ refers too - here $A$ is the algebra of analytic functions in the unit disc and continuous on the unit circle so $f(0)=a_0$ (the value at $0$ in the unit disc where $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ which becomes indeed the Fourier series on the circle) not anything to do with the boundary or $(-\pi,\pi)$ and the result is obvious as noted above by orthogonality

Comment: @Conrad can you please explain the connection the book is making between integrals that vanish and functions that vanish at the origin. I still do not-whether these are functions on the circle or disk-understand what the idea is.

Comment: $A$ is the algebra of analytic functions in the unit disc that are continuous on the closed unit disc; so a function in $A$ can be written as $\sum_{n \ge 0}a_nz^n$ and its Fourier series (and boundary circle restriction abusing notation a little and using $f(\theta)=f(e^{i\theta})$) ) is given by $f(\theta)=\sum_{n \ge 0}a_ne^{in\theta}$; so by orthogonality, we have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)d\theta=2\pi a_0=2\pi f(0)$

Comment: @Conrad I understand the isomorphism between the two spaces; but isn’t this the question I asked, I.e., why when you integrate a function of this type you get its value at zero?How can this type of integration be valid? If you let $n$ vary over $\mathbb{Z}$ you will get all continuous functions on the disc. But the integral of a continuous function is not it’s value at $0$.

Comment: You misunderstand what $A$ is; it is the space of continuous functions on the closed unit disc that are analytic in the unit disc; their restriction to the unit circle is quite complicated to understand - their Fourier series have no negative powers so are of the type $\sum_{n \ge 0}a_ne^{in\theta}$, they have bounded variation iff they are absolutely continuous (which is not true of continuous functions on the unit circle in general) and contain some weird functions like Littlewood-Hardy famous $\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac {e^{in \log n}e^{i n\theta}}{\sqrt n \log^{3/2} n}$ which is barely $L^2$

Comment: @Conrad you just wrote that when you integrate the Fourier series of a function in $A$ you get its value at $0$, did you not? That is exactly the question I asked.

Comment: Yes that's correct but the $0$ here is the one of the unit disc not the $0$ of $(-\pi, \pi)$ in $L^{\infty}(-\pi, \pi)$; in other words while the integral of $f$ is on the unit circle, its value is the value of the analytic extension of $f$ to the unit disc taken at the zero of the unit disc

Comment: @Conrad so how are you integrating the series to get that?

Comment: the integral of the unit circle of $e^{in \theta}$ is zero by periodicity unless $n=0$ since the function has the antiderivative $e^{in \theta}/(in)$ which is periodic so has same value at the ends unless $n=0$ when you integrate $1$ so get $2\pi$ since the antiderivative of $1$ is not periodic anymore; so integrating term by term $\sum_{n \ge 0}a_n e^{in \theta}$ gives precisely $2\pi a_0$

Comment: So all you are saying is that Hoffman is identifying $a_{o}$ with $f(0)$? That’s literally the only thing I was confused about. Now I completely understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you understand $f(0)$ as the value at $0$ of a function defined on $(-\pi,\pi)$ then the function
  $$f(x):=1-e^{ix}$$
  is a counterexample:
  $$f\in A,\quad f(0)=0,\quad\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\left(x\right)dx=2\pi.$$
- However, this interpretation is not compatible with Hoffman's proof, which uses that
  $$\forall f\in A\quad\int_{-\pi}^\pi\left[f(\theta)-f(0)\right]d\theta=0.\tag{*}$$
  For this property to hold, $f(0)$ must be interpreted as the value, at the center $0$ of the unit disc $D$, of the analytic function $F$ on $D$ whose limit on the circle $\partial D$ is $f.$ If $f(x)=e^{ikx}$ then $F(z)=z^k,$ hence $F(0)=0$ if $k\ge1,$ whereas $F(1)=1$ if $k=0.$ Thus, the property $(*)$ above reduces to the obvious:
  $$\forall n\ge1\quad\int_{-\pi}^\pi\left[e^{in\theta}-0\right]d\theta=0.$$

This was understandable from Hoffman's previous page:

> "We denote by $A$ the collection of functions which are continuous on the closed unit disc and analytic at each interior point. [...] $$\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{|z|\le1}|f(z)|=\sup|f(e^{it})|.$$
> [...] Thus, we may identify the functions in $A$ with their boundary values".

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you but the OP mentionned "Lebesgue measure", and the excerpt takes $d\theta,$ not $ie^{i\theta}d\theta.$

Comment: Thank you @BrianMoehring for insisting: now I read Hoffman's text and I am completely lost, and you made me eager to understand. If $\mathrm d\theta=ie^{ix}\mathrm dx,$ I understand why the first term of the sum is $0,$ but I don't understand why the second one is, i.e. why $\int\mathrm d\theta=2\pi.$

Comment: @Brian $f(0)$ refers to the value at $0$ in the unit disc not at anything to do with the circle; the OP missed the important stuff that $A$ are actually analytic functions in the unit disc continuous on the boundary but the reference makes it clear; then indeed $f(0)=a_0$ the constant Fourier term

Comment: @Conrad Thank you! What a relief! I shall improve my answer thanks to your comment.

Comment: @AnneBauval what I was confused about was $f(0)=a_{0}$. Even though this was mentioned several times, all the comments about other spaces, measures, etc. obscured the simple fact that this is meant as a purely formal identification.